# How to link (map) products between two Magento websites?

Tags: magento, mapping, e-commerce

I would like to develop TWO Magento websites under different domain names domainONE.com and domainTWO.com
I would like to have SOME (not all) products (Approximately 200 out of 5000) on both websites to be the same, but the Titles, Pictures and Descriptions must be different. The products must be mapped/linked somehow, most importantly the stock MUST be the same on both websites  for these particular products and the stock must change on both websites when the product sells on either one of the websites

Example:
domainONE.COM (has 5000 products)
domainTWO.com (200 same products as on domainONE.COM, but the Title, Description and Pictures must be different. However when the product sells on EITHER domains the stock must be synchronized between both domains.

Any solutions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's your exact problem?

Comment: I do not know how to link SOME products from two different magento websites.

Answer (score 1):

The Magento is made to solve problem like yours.

It is noy just two, you can share products between hundreds of sites. In fact many store owner configure Magento like you wanted to do. You just got the thr terminology wrong. They called it Multi-store management. In Magento, you can run multiple websites in single installation and have different product name, description or any property for each website - imagine scenario of multi-linguel websites.

You have to read and understand Magento's multi-store management at Wiki page http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work/

Comment: I really appreciate your response! I did use terminology wrong. One thing I am not sure can be done with MULTI-STORE is having same products under different names, desription's, url's, titles and pictures on two websites BUT still link them two together so the stock changes on both.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Magento multi-store works exactly same way you want.

Comment: If I may ask one more question, Do both websites must have the same Template and be from the same Hosting provider ?

Comment: You can have different or same template as you wish. But both site should be hosted in same provider in same path.

Answer (score 0):

Magento already provide this type of feature.

All you need to do is, set up a multisite magento website.

And yes stock(Inventory) is managed globally by Magento, so I think in short this is all you need.

Below are some links that could help you:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-on-the-fly/multiple-sites/

Regards,
Milan

Comment: I just looked at both links. This seems to answer my question. However I do no see one thing, how to link products by some characteristic other than  description's, url's, titles and pictures. The products will be the same, but I don't want them to look and be described the same way, as well the titles should be different. Otherwise it will be noticeable its the same store, probably even bad for Google as the information on both websites is Copied.

Comment: actually to differentiate the products attributes value. You have to define the scope of that attribute for particular product while adding/editing that product.

Comment: These links are dead now